# How to sort elements in individual rows in ascending order?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have matrix with `n` lines and `m` columns, suppose the following

```
[5 6 2 6 8
 7 6 9 0 4  
 8 0 9 5 4]
```

I want to generate a matrix in which, every line is sorted in ascending order, for example, vector `(1,m)`, vector `(2,m)`, vector `(3,m)`, and so on:

```
[2 5 6 6 8    
 0 4 6 7 9
 0 4 5 8 9]
```

How can I do this? Do I have to use a loop to achieve this?

Comment: Do you really need a loop? Without one is okay?

Comment: I need a loop to repeat the code because it works with vectors not matrix.. B and I are vectors, so I cannot put the "vector" (variable) as a matrix because they don't have the same dimension..

Comment: Actually sort works with matrices also, not only with vectors. It can sort *every* row in a matrix, if you tell it so. And if you don't believe me, you should believe the MATLAB documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html

Comment: Your code somehow does not translate to the question you are asking which refers to the sorting of a matrix in each row (which already has been answered here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for loops. [`sort`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) automatically works in a [vectorized manner](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html). By default it sorts the input array along the first non-singleton dimension. To sort each row you need to specify `2` as an additional input (sort along the *second* dimension).

So, denoting your matrix as `x`,  just use

```
sort(x,2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. In fact, I need loop to repeat the code .. could you please help me?

Comment: @NourhaineNefzi Did you bother trying out the code Luis gave you? If you did, you'd see that it does exactly what you ask for. Give it a try and if you still don't get the results you want, add your results to your question and explain how it is incorrect.